# Angular - ng-init statement - the statement does not work

Tags: angularjs

why does the following statement work but not the one after

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body ng-app>
 <table ng-init='products = [{"name":"blah", "code":"ten12", "available":"yes","price":243}]'>
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td>Available</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td>{{product.code}}</td>
            <td>{{product.available}}</td>
            <td>{{product.price}}</td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

and this one does not work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body ng-app>
 <table ng-init='products = [{"name":"blah", "code":"ten12", "available":"yes","price":243}]'>
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td>Available</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{products.name}}</td>
            <td>{{products.code}}</td>
            <td>{{products.available}}</td>
            <td>{{products.price}}</td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

the only difference i see in the above two statements is that second one is missing ng-repeat statement but products variable is initialised in both of them. so in second statement if i directly call products shouldn't it be called atleast one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both of the examples, `products` is an array (in this case, with one item).

In the first one, you're iterating through the items in the array with `ng-repeat`, which works fine. In the second one, though, you are trying to display properties `name`, `code`, and so on of the array, not any of the items, and arrays do not have those properties, so nothing is displayed. (Conversely, for example, you would get a value back from `products.length` but not `product.length`, because arrays have a length property while the items don't.)

You could display the properties of the first item in the array by using

```
        <td>{{products[0].name}}</td>
        <td>{{products[0].code}}</td>
        <td>{{products[0].available}}</td>
        <td>{{products[0].price}}</td>
```

instead. But that'll do exactly that, only display the first one. You need to use `ng-repeat` as in the first example if you want to display the data for each of them dynamically.